# Uploading image using pyimgur to imgur, using images link

Tags: python, imgur

I was interested in uploading images to the imgur API. In the docs to upload the image

```
import pyimgur

CLIENT_ID = "Your_applications_client_id"
PATH = "A Filepath to an image on your computer"

im = pyimgur.Imgur(CLIENT_ID)
uploaded_image = im.upload_image(PATH, title="Uploaded with PyImgur")
print(uploaded_image.title)
print(uploaded_image.date)
print(uploaded_image.url)
print(uploaded_image.link)
```

I am curious if someone knows how to instead of using a path( have the image saved locally), just have a link to a image to upload to imgur. I feel like it exists due to the fact with the GUI website you can enter a picture link and can then upload.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Imgur.upload_image()` method takes a `url` argument, simply pass it a URL of an image to add:

```
uploaded_image = im.upload_image(url=URL_OF_IMAGE, title="Uploaded with PyImgur")
```

You must either provide a path or a URL, but not both.

See the [`upload_image()` documentation](https://pyimgur.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html#pyimgur.__init__.Imgur.upload_image) for all arguments it accepts:

> Upload the image at either path or url.
>
> - **path** – The path to the image you want to upload.
> - **url** – The url to the image you want to upload.

Comment: This is literally the best response I've ever seen on here. Thank you for the thoughtful response so quickly.

Comment: @Eigenvalue: pretty sure Martijn has posted much much better and less based-on-reading-the-obvious-reference answers.

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ: I found the documentation only after checking the [source code](https://github.com/Damgaard/PyImgur/blob/master/pyimgur/__init__.py#L1102-L1143), in this case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters awesome :) you work here like I do for my job, just 30dB faster.